# Can PHP have not root permissions, if it is runned via root cron job?

Tags: php, cron, root

In `/etc/crontab` i see a job like this:

`15 15  *   *   *   root    /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php`

So, with some other settings, cat this php script have not root access, when runned?

My system administrator says, that it's safe and PHP script have no root access. But i'm doubt.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this if you want to avoid the script from being run as root:

```
15 15  *   *   *   anotheruser    /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```

In your version the script IS INDEED run as root. The cron line does explicitly say so.
I guess your systems administrator and you had a misunderstanding and he meant this:
if php-fpm or apache-mod-php would run the script, it would run with the user php-fpm or apache run as themselves.

Comment: I know that. The question is: Can PHP have not root rights, if it is runned via root cron job?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? Do you want to make sure the script never has root permissions? Do you want to run the script with other users' permissions even if the script was started as root?

Comment: Can PHP have not root permissions, when it's runned via root cron job?
I want to run the script with other user's permissions even if the script was started as root.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a wrapper for the script. i.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash
RUNAS=user1

if [ "${USER}" == "root" ]
then
  # use sudo to change user
  sudo -u $RUNAS -H /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
else
  # run as the current user
  /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
fi
```

otherwise you could just add sudo to the cron-task:

```
15 15  *   *   *   root    sudo -u user1 -H /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```